# Add shadow on a svg <path>

Tags: css, svg

I'm trying to put a modern shadow on a particular part of a svg.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 162 63.25">
  <g style="isolation:isolate">
    <g>
      <g>
        <path d="M149.376,39.75l-49,23.5v-47Z" fill="#811818"/>
        <path d="M149.376,39.75H6.688L30.279,22.274,6.624,4.75H149.376Z" fill="#b51c1c"/>
      </g>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

I tried using the filter but the edge are visible and it's too blury:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 162 63.25">
  <g style="isolation:isolate">
    <g>
      <g>
        <filter id="dropshadow" x="-2" y="-2" width="200" height="200">
          <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="1"/>
        </filter>
        <path d="M149.376,39.75l-49,23.5v-47Z" fill="#811818"/>
        <path style="stroke: rgba(0,0,0,0.19); stroke-width: 0.2; filter: url('#dropshadow');" d="M149.376,39.75H6.688L30.279,22.274,6.624,4.75H149.376Z" fill="#b51c1c"/>
      </g>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

I'm expecting to use some modern css shadow like (https://codepen.io/sdthornton/pen/wBZdXq) and don't crop the original svg. I also expect to use less shadow on the top of it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is what you want, you can just change the values in the filter to fit your needs.

in plain simple words, not to completact thing:

**feOffset**: x, y to move the blur shadow effect back and forth.
**filter**: height to move it up and down

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 169 67.25">
  <g style="isolation:isolate">
    <g>
      <g>
        <defs>
          <filter id="dropshadow" height="122%">
            <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="1" /> 
            <feOffset in="blur" dx="0.7" dy="0.7" result="offsetBlur"/>
            <feOffset dx="1" dy="1" result="offsetblur" />
            <feFlood flood-color="#3D4574" flood-opacity="0.3" result="offsetColor"/>
            <feComposite in="offsetColor" in2="offsetBlur" operator="in" result="offsetBlur"/>
          </filter>
        </defs>
        <use xlink:href="#path1" filter="url(#dropshadow)"></use>
        <path id="path1" d="M149.376,39.75l-49,23.5v-47Z" fill="#811818"/>
        <use xlink:href="#path2" filter="url(#dropshadow)"></use>
        <path id="path2" style="stroke: rgba(0,0,0,0.19); stroke-width: 0.2;" d="M149.376,39.75H6.688L30.279,22.274,6.624,4.75H149.376Z" fill="#b51c1c"/>
      
      </g>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Do you know why the shadow is being cut at this area ? https://i.imgur.com/klyQs5B.png

Comment: @executable increas a viewbox a little

Comment: @executable this can be fixed by increasing the viewbox, will check it now

Comment: How can I make it less "dark" the shadow, I already adjusted `stroke: rgba(0,0,0,0.19);`

Comment: It seems like it's coming from `SourceAlpha`

Comment: Fixed, check it now, I added feFlood, just change the attributes of this tag to change the darkness and color of the shadow.

Comment: Is there any way to extend the bottom height of the shadow without breaking the blur effect?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207282/discussion-between-mamoun-othman-and-executable).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using custom svg filter you can achieve easily the expected result using the standard CSS drop-shadow filter

ie: `filter: drop-shadow(0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,.5));`

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 162 63.25">
  <g style="isolation:isolate">
    <path d="M149.376,39.75l-49,23.5v-47Z" fill="#811818"/>
    <path style="stroke: rgba(0,0,0,0.19); stroke-width: 0.2; filter: drop-shadow(0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,.5));" d="M149.376,39.75H6.688L30.279,22.274,6.624,4.75H149.376Z" fill="#b51c1c"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: ugh... you're right. It doesn't work properly on chrome (firefox displays it right).
Possible reason: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=109224